# How to use python to merge two files with duplicate values in key columns and keep all permutations possible？

Tags: python, database, data-processing

Two text files are respectively a.txt and b.txt, how to use the second column of the first file and the first column of the second file as the key column, use python to merge the two files and output the third file form? Because the key column has duplicate values, how to keep all the possibilities?[a.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXw8i.png)[b.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smyJh.png)[c.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AtBt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use pandas?

Running this:

```
import pandas as pd;
a = pd.read_csv('a.txt',names=['chr','capletter','number'])
b = pd.read_csv('b.txt',names=['capletter','letter'])
c = a.merge(b,left_on='capletter',right_on='capletter')
c.to_csv('c.txt',header=False,index=False)
```

From a.txt:

```
chr1,A,1
chr2,B,2
chr3,B,3
CHR3,C,4
```

And b.txt:

```
A,a
B,b
B,c
```

You'll  get c.txt:

```
chr1,A,1,a
chr2,B,2,b
chr2,B,2,c
chr3,B,3,b
chr3,B,3,c
```